# Expression to Exclude rows that have a specific column blank

Tags: case

I want to exclude entire rows that have blanks for a specific column....I dont want to show a row that has the first name column as a blank...I was thinking maybe a case statement would help with this

case when [First Name] = blank then exclude???

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: are you talking about a database access or a language/array access ?

Comment: Sorry Ph.T I dont knw the difference between the two...I am very, very new to expressions so please excuse my noobness :0(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add a calculated column that would be used as a flag, and then filter on the flag.

if(Len([First Name])>0,1,0)

Now I am able to filter on the calculated column to show only rows that have 1 in it (which will be the rows where First Name is not empty).

This doesn't delete the row from the dataset, but has the same effect in visualizations as if it had been.

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL, in general you could do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE myCol IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I honestly dont know...I am using Spotfire and it will allow me to enter custom expressions like case, when, count, if , then, else..and a whole list of other functions to include property functions, over functions, binning functions...etc